# Android Login Register php mysql , forceclose when register form

Tags: java, android

i'm tired, and i dont know how to fix my application .. my problem is, everytime i'm register and filling edittext until click button "register" my application forceclose, but data was entry in mysql .. this my code:

RegisterActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.latihan.Utils.DatabaseHandler;
import com.latihan.Utils.UserFunctions;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";



    EditText inputFirstName;
    EditText inputLastName;
    EditText inputUsername;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    Button btnRegister;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);




        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bktologin);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });



        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (  ( !inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputFirstName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputLastName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    if ( inputUsername.getText().toString().length() > 4 ){
                        NetAsync(view);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Username should be minimum 5 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "One or more fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){


            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessRegister().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }





    private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        /**
         * Defining Process dialog
         **/
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String email,password,fname,lname,uname;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
            fname = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
            lname = inputLastName.getText().toString();
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            uname= inputUsername.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password);

            return json;


        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");


                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");



                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        /**
                         * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                         * Launch Registered screen
                         **/

                        Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegistredActivity.class);


                        registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(registered);


                        finish();
                    }

                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                    }
                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                    }

                }


                else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


            }
        }}
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }
```

JSONParse.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONListfromURL(String url,List<NameValuePair> params){

        //initialize
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        //http post
        try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //try parse the string to a JSON object
        try{
            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

    public void SendJSONToURL(String url,List<NameValuePair> params){

        //http post
        try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            httpclient.execute(httppost);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

and this my logcat

```
>06-10 14:34:36.120 9915-9950/com.app.latihan E/JSON: <br />
                                                               <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-deprecated' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
                                                               <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\aa\include\DB_Connect.php on line <i>18</i></th></tr>
                                                               <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
                                                               <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
                                                               <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.4669</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>151232</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\aa\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
                                                               <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.6559</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>171112</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_Functions->__construct(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\aa\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>13</td></tr>
                                                               <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.7570</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>174872</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_Connect->connect(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\aa\include\DB_Functions.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\DB_Functions.php<b>:</b>13</td></tr>
                                                               <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.7661</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>175384</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect' target='_new'>mysql_connect</a>
                                                               (  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\aa\include\DB_Connect.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\DB_Connect.php<b>:</b>18</td></tr>
                                                               </table></font>
                                                               {"tag":"register","success":1,"error":0,"user":{"fname":"test1","lname":"test2","email":"test3@gmail.com","uname":"test4","uid":"575a6d8b4cc012.68231874","created_at":"2016-06-10 14:34:35"}}
    06-10 14:34:36.120 9915-9950/com.app.latihan E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
    06-10 14:34:36.156 9915-9915/com.app.latihan D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

>--------- beginning of crash
    06-10 14:34:36.156 9915-9915/com.app.latihan E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.app.latihan, PID: 9915
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.app.latihan.RegisterActivity$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(RegisterActivity.java:229)
                                                                             at com.app.latihan.RegisterActivity$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(RegisterActivity.java:186)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

UserFunction.class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.content.Context;
import com.app.latihan.Utils.JSONParser;


public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    //URL of the PHP API
    private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/aa/";
    private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/aa/";
    private static String forpassURL = "http://10.0.2.2/aa/";
    private static String chgpassURL = "http://10.0.2.2/aa/";


    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";
    private static String forpass_tag = "forpass";
    private static String chgpass_tag = "chgpass";


    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        return json;
    }


    public JSONObject chgPass(String newpas, String email){
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", chgpass_tag));

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newpas", newpas));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(chgpassURL, params);
        return json;
    }





    /**
     * Function to reset the password
     **/

    public JSONObject forPass(String forgotpassword){
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", forpass_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("forgotpassword", forgotpassword));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(forpassURL, params);
        return json;
    }





    public JSONObject registerUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL,params);
        return json;
    }


    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Resets the temporary data stored in SQLite Database
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }

}
```

i use Android Studio
Please someone help me please

Comment: Hard to tell, but any one of the `getString` seems to be called on a null variable.

Comment: Future note: The logcat is good, and thanks for providing code. However, 1) NullPointerExceptions are so frequent in Java programs that you should be able to trace the cause down yourself and 2) You've posted too much code. You will want to read about creating a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

**Your server response is incorrect**.This is the response you are getting from your server :

> ( ! ) Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\aa\include\DB_Connect.php on line *18*
>                                                              Call Stack
>                                                              #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
>                                                              10.4669151232{main}(  )..\index.php**:**0
>                                                              20.6559171112DB_Functions->__construct(  )..\index.php**:**13
>                                                              30.7570174872DB_Connect->connect(  )..\DB_Functions.php**:**13
>                                                              40.7661175384http://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect' target='_new'>mysql_connect
>                                                              (  )..\DB_Connect.php**:**18
>                                                              
>                                                              {"tag":"register","success":1,"error":0,"user":{"fname":"test1","lname":"test2","email":"test3@gmail.com","uname":"test4","uid":"575a6d8b4cc012.68231874","created_at":"2016-06-10 14:34:35"}}

**I which this lines are meaning less :**

> ( ! ) Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\aa\include\DB_Connect.php on line *18*
>                                                              Call Stack
>                                                              #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
>                                                              10.4669151232{main}(  )..\index.php**:**0
>                                                              20.6559171112DB_Functions->__construct(  )..\index.php**:**13
>                                                              30.7570174872DB_Connect->connect(  )..\DB_Functions.php**:**13
>                                                              40.7661175384http://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect' target='_new'>mysql_connect
>                                                              (  )..\DB_Connect.php**:**18

***The above text can not be converted to JSONObject/JsonArray this is the reason, Why your code is giving Error..!!***

Please change the code at your server side. This will be the **correct response** from server:

```
{"tag":"register","success":1,"error":0,"user":{"fname":"test1","lname":"test2","email":"test3@gmail.com","uname":"test4","uid":"575a6d8b4cc012.68231874","created_at":"2016-06-10 14:34:35"}}
```

I think there is some error in your server side code. Contact your API developer..!!

For avoiding Further error like this. Please change your code like below.

**In your `ProcessRegister` AsyncTask:**

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        try {
            if (json!=null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
               //Your code
            }


            else{
               //your code
            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is caused by a `NULLPointerException`, this is because you try to used `json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS)`, but JSON Object is `null`. NULL is caused because your `doInBackground` return a `null` object, particularly your `userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password)` return a `null` object.

Try to fix this or post your `UserFunction` class to help you better.

Comment: While you have pointed out the problem, this is not quite an answer. The other answer is the correct solution, and that being said, the UserFunction class isn't really needed

Comment: this my userfunction class @cricket_007

Comment: @JetliMoslem I'm not sure what you are trying to tell me, but you excluded that file from the code in your question. That is what this answer has asked you to include. There is an 'edit' link under your question if you would like to include it, but you still should follow the [mcve] rules.

Comment: @cricket_007  i was update my post, thankyou for help me using stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

@cricket_007 this UserFunction.java on my application

```
i

mport java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.content.Context;
    import com.app.latihan.Utils.JSONParser;


    public class UserFunctions {

        private JSONParser jsonParser;

        //URL of the PHP API
        private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/aa/";
        private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/aa/";
        private static String forpassURL = "http://10.0.2.2/aa/";
        private static String chgpassURL = "http://10.0.2.2/aa/";


        private static String login_tag = "login";
        private static String register_tag = "register";
        private static String forpass_tag = "forpass";
        private static String chgpass_tag = "chgpass";


        // constructor
        public UserFunctions(){
            jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        }

        /**
         * Function to Login
         **/

        public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
            return json;
        }

        /**
         * Function to change password
         **/

        public JSONObject chgPass(String newpas, String email){
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", chgpass_tag));

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newpas", newpas));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(chgpassURL, params);
            return json;
        }





        /**
         * Function to reset the password
         **/

        public JSONObject forPass(String forgotpassword){
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", forpass_tag));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("forgotpassword", forgotpassword));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(forpassURL, params);
            return json;
        }






        /**
         * Function to  Register
         **/
        public JSONObject registerUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String password){
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL,params);
            return json;
        }


        /**
         * Function to logout user
         * Resets the temporary data stored in SQLite Database
         * */
        public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
            db.resetTables();
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO,You can click on edit below your question and add this code inside that...!!

Comment: And refer my answer. It will provide you the solution. Just try once :) @Jetli Moslem..!!

Comment: i'm sorry im new user on stackoverflow and this my first time using this @jankigadhiya

Comment: It's ok.. Delete this.. see under your question you will have having edit option click on that or else click this link http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37743939/edit and Edit your question Add this code in that and save edit..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya thankyou for your help, but how i cant implement to my code, i'm beginner android studio